# How to add new element to array which inside nested object by its path?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, nested, event-handling

I want to add new element to array which inside nested object by using its path. I searched but didn't anything about that. For example my object is :

```
const sample = {
  enum: 4,
  key: "COMMON_TYPE",
  steps: [
    {
      title: "STEP ONE",
      description: "des1",
      instructions: [
        {
          icon: "step_power",
          label: {
            text: "METHOD_OVEN_DEFAULT_STEP_ONE_ICONTEXT",
            color: "A11111",
            location: "top",
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      title: "STEP TWO",
      description: "des2",
      instructions: [
        {
          icon: "step_power",
          label: {
            text: "METHOD_OVEN_DEFAULT_STEP_TWO_ICONTEXT_ONE",
            color: "A11111",
            location: "top",
          },
        },   
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

and I want to new element for this path 'steps.0.instructions' and second item should be copy of first index for that array. In  onClick event I got path of key as 'steps.0.instructions'. Now I need a function which return newObject for given issue. My output should be like this:

```
const sample = {
  enum: 4,
  key: "COMMON_TYPE",
  steps: [
    {
      title: "STEP ONE",
      description: "des1",
      instructions: [
        {
          icon: "step_power",
          label: {
            text: "METHOD_OVEN_DEFAULT_STEP_ONE_ICONTEXT",
            color: "A11111",
            location: "top",
          },
       {
          icon: "step_power",
          label: {
            text: "METHOD_OVEN_DEFAULT_STEP_ONE_ICONTEXT",
            color: "A11111",
            location: "top",
          }
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      title: "STEP TWO",
      description: "des2",
      instructions: [
        {
          icon: "step_power",
          label: {
            text: "METHOD_OVEN_DEFAULT_STEP_TWO_ICONTEXT_ONE",
            color: "A11111",
            location: "top",
          },
        },   
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

Thanks..

Comment: Do you want a whole new `sample` object or to mutate the original one?

Answer (score 0):

use unshift function to add new item to the beginning of array.
like

```
sample.steps.instructions.unshift( {
    icon: "step_power#2",
    label: {
      text: "METHOD_OVEN_DEFAULT_STEP_ONE_ICONTEXT",
      color: "A11111",
      location: "top",
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna copy an object, lookup what deep copy means.

Here are some helpful links:

- [stackoverflow: how to deep copy in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)
- [MDN StructuredClone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone)

Answer (score -1):

This does what you ask for.

I used `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sample))` for a deep copy. You can do it in your preferred way.

```
const addToPath = (sample, path) => {
    const parts = path.split(".")
    const newSample = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sample))

    const instructionsArray = newSample[parts[0]][parts[1]][parts[2]]
    instructionsArray.push(instructionsArray[0])

    return newSample
}
```

And it will be called as follows:

```
const newSample = addToPath(sample, "steps.0.instructions")
```